# Intel 80386 Programmer's Reference Manual: Interpreting bit numbering in example data structure

Tags: memory, x86, intel, endianness, manual

[image: Intel data structure format]

> In illustrations of data structures in memory, smaller addresses appear at the lower-right part of the figure; addresses increase toward the left and upwards. Bit positions are numbered from right to left. Figure 1-1 illustrates this convention.

From my understanding, most modern computers are byte addressable meaning the combinations of bits correspond to one byte in memory. My question is how does that translate to the example diagram given above?

I see Fig 1-1 is showing 32 bytes in sequence, and as we move towards the top left, the address of each byte is increasing, but as for the bit offset I am confused. How are the bit offsets related to the bytes? Especially the top columns numbers 0, 7, 15, 23, 31.

Comment: A byte usually (always on x86) consists of 8 bits. So bits 0..7 make up one byte, bits 8..15 make up another byte, etc.

Comment: Oh, so the bit offsets are referring to the actual data of the byte rather than the address?

Comment: Yup, 386 needs to define bit-numbering because of instructions like [`bt [mem], reg`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bt) that bit-index into memory.  Fortunately there's nothing weird, and it's the same bit-ordering you'd get after loading into a register that makes right shifts divide by 2, etc.